# Update Installed MSI Version from EXE

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, versioning

I've created an application that installs via MSI with version number X.X.X - lets say 1.0.0. Next, we created a custom self update process that uses no form of MSI. (We are replacing files via code.) This custom self update process is required and enables us to manage a large number of users remotely and quickly. We've had this running for a while now. The one thing that is bugging me is that the Version displayed on the Programs and Features screen for our application is still 1.0.0. Is there a way to update the program version from the main executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from comment to answer for better readability, and discussion of facts to your question and concerning environment:

First let's see about your proposal of changing the value of `DisplayVersion` in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{MSI ProductCode}
```

for 32 bit MSI setups (most setups operate still here, often even if containing 64-bit or independent (e.g. .NET) code, but that is another matter) or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{MSI ProductCode}
```

for 64 bit MSI setups. First, this is only the place for machine-wide ("LOCAL_MACHINE") setups, not for user-dependent setups, but that's ok, as this is standard.

It is not best practice to edit DisplayVersion. At least, it can be subject to discussions, if to edit it. In fact, it is a free string, and a number of setups out there are using this, calling their version not "1.0", but "V1.0" or "1.0a" or similar.
If doing this, it is the less worst to do it in a custom action in the msi itself (at the very end).

At least, as an argument against those who call changing this key forbidden: This is not the place on which the MSI logically operates with versions, this version is not used for version compares. In fact it is just an output string.

OTOH, it can be overridden again by an original setup (MSI) repair/update/reinstall. So warning NOT to change manually has a background.

Additionally: 
There are Windows versions, especially older ones, who have update problems, so changing registry value does not immediately reflect the control panel view. There is an ARP cache for example holding all the install entries. I would not expect Windows 7 or higher to have these problems, but having seen problems in the past and knowing the ARP cache still exists is making me cautious here.

What I recommend, and I would call it good practice, is to not change this number, but let belong it to native MSI.

Instad make MSI setups invisble for users in control panel ("Programs and Features" or **ARP** how we still call it in the MSI and setup community because of it's older name):

Either set the `ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT` property in your MSI fix to 1 (normally hex 1, but because it's you, you can only choose decimal 1 :-)).

Or provide `ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1` as a command line parameter to any MSI setup you want, while installing.

In fact this is what Microsoft is doing with SQL server, Visual Studio, Office setups too. They consist of multiple setups which shall behave like invisible (setup) components.

Alternatively you can make (any) MSI setup "invisible" *after install*: By simply changing the registry value `SystemComponent` (or adding) in the registry directly to 1 .
*But this is not clean, again*, because a repair or update or reinstall could change this again. But it would not break anything- at worst invisible setups would become visible.

Then you build another setup (maybe "main" setup) for the visual ARP settings or you just create a complete MSI independent key in the registry under the "Uninstall" key mentioned above. (Either in a program or in the "normal" MSI setup).  This can be a GUID or a normal name. Look in your registry and you find a number of examples there for non-GUIDs, e.g. by Adobe, etc. Every non-GUID is not a "Windows Installer" (MSI) setup, but of course also some GUID-like-entries can be by non-MSI setups.

The main advantage is: This new `DisplayVersion` in the MSI-independent key can be controlled by your own.

Comment: Last time I checked, to be visible for a user, an own created registry key under "Uninstall" has to have at least two nonempty values for "DisplayName" and "UninstallString". Normally "DisplayVersion" is added too, as I wrote. And there are a lot of other helpful entries you can provide estimated diskspace and installation path of your "artificial" product on your own.

Comment: As may be of interest, the "UninstallString" and also "ModifyPath" are totally unimportant in the other case, _IF_ it is a MSI setup. You can change or delete them, it doesn't bother Windows Installer, doing it's normal MSI uninstall process, searching the cached MSI and performing it's work reading it.

Comment: I would read Windows Installer Rule # 21 as I think it applies here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/12/595950.aspx

Comment: Partly. Creating own keys in "Uninstall" area is not only allowed but mandatory for setups, e.g. bootstrapper or other non-MSI setups. And working with ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT is fine too. # 21 applies of course to changing SystemComponent or DisplayVersion of a MSI setup directly in registry. As I mentioned.

Comment: Since we're going into the design questions again, I will state that our software handles uninstalling by cleaning up added files, disables advertised shortcuts to prevent auto-repairing, and we never send our customers the MSI. We provide the hardware and software and the MSI never ships. In fact, we install once and image the rest of the devices. So most of these repair concerns are not for us. We aren't working on a standard client. We have a closed system on a closed network so considerations are a bit different.

Comment: I've been involved in some very complex systems for the DoD in similar circumstances.  They used to ship "bricks" to the customer like you describe.  I can tell you for a fact that it really doesn't matter and that everything goes better if you follow good design practices.  If you really want to do your own thing the way you are doing it,  just stop using MSI all together as I doubt it's providing you very little value the way that you are leverage it.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I've also worked on systems for the DoD. By the way, the project I'm working (as I've stated before) wasn't my design decision. I am working with an old code base that was already using the MSI installer. We no longer install this software on the customers computers. But hey, maybe I can tell my boss to tell the customer to get their admin to uninstall all of the software on their thousands of devices and reinstall using a different installer. I'm sure that will go over well.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you do.  That's the only way to eliminate the technical debt that has been accumulated.  I spent 5 years working for a company leading a team of 12 build and install engineers supporting 400 developers.  We had a product line development environment where we assembled different combinations of assets into variant products with various classification levels.  Each product/installer had a complexity level similar to Visual Studio. We did about 100,000 build per year  It was a complete mess when I got there with lots of customer complaints.Trust me, I've walked your path.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reinvent patching.  Windows Installer doesn't support this and there's no way to do what you are trying to do.

Update: [Tao of the Windows Installer, Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/12/595950.aspx)

> **Rule 21: Avoid Using Configuration Data You Don’t Own**
>
> As part of the initial design for the Installer, the consistency of
>   installations was achieved via Microsoft taking ownership of the code
>   for the install engine. This includes the location and format of all
>   configuration data. This data is managed by the Installer and direct
>   access by users or applications is discouraged; in fact some of the
>   data is encoded to make it very difficult to manipulate manually.
>
> You should not try to peek directly into Windows Installer
>   configuration information. Instead, use the Windows Installer API to
>   get the information you need. Accessing the data this way ensures that
>   your package or application will continue to work even if the
>   underlying configuration data changes location or format.

In this case the API is [MsiGetProductInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130(v=vs.85).aspx).  This function returns `INSTALLPROPERTY_VERSIONSTRING` which is which is the [ProductVersion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx).  This API has no mechanism to set the ProductVerion because MSI does this internally during [PublishProduct Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370932(v=vs.85).aspx).  If you look in the registry you'll find it under HKCR\Installer\Products\PackedGuid\Version.  The Packed Guid is a "Darwin transform" of your ProductCode in DWORD format.  ProductVersion is stored in DWORD format with 1 byte for Major 1 byte for Minor and 2 bytes for build.  This is because ProductVersion ignores the 4th field although it is stored in ARP.

This registry structure is obfusacated in an attempt to encourage rule 21.  Don't mess with Windows Installer configuration data out of process.  Let MSI handle it.

Comment: The patching process is actually working quite well and much better than the experience I've had with MSI's. But I find it hard to believe that there is no way to update the version of an installed application except through an MSI file.

Comment: I can imagine all sorts of problems.  Delete a file and hit repair, you get the old one not the new one.  DLL reference counts get messed up.  Uninstalls fail cleanly.  Been there, done that.  I understand why you are wanting to do it and I understand why it appears to be a good design but I can assure you that it is not.

Comment: We've implemented it for the last two years. It wasn't my decision either. This isn't a design question, this is a how to update the version question.

Comment: The reason there is no way to update it is because MSI owns the version number.  They only expose the ProductVersion property to you in the MSI.  The PublishProduct standard action is then responsible for the implementation in it's own meta data (as exposed by Win32_Product) and the Uninstall registry key for ARP/PF.  It's private data and no API exists because no valid user story exists to create it.

Comment: Down vote me all you want.  I answered your question: it isn't possible.

Comment: I just did it with the registry setting and I'm going to post it as an answer. So there is in fact a way.

Comment: I can understand both of you. I don't think there is a reason to start a flame war or sth. I agree with Christopher as a consultant, that what you are doing with "own patching" is the opposite from what a MSI expert would recommend, opposite to "best practice". One of the reasons is, that installed products have a lifetime under Windows (Installer) ! But OTOH, now you have a quite working solution so far you oversee, so just let us clear, if you have not overlooked sth. :-))   In other words, it is not unfair to ask for details concerning your work, but nor is it to point out potential flaws.

Comment: @Philm My problem with this answer is that it isn't. It should probably be a comment if anything. The question states that this has already been implemented. Debating whether or not it is a good idea isn't relevant in an answer. This question asked specifically how to update the version that is displayed. I down voted because this wasn't an attempt to answer the actual question at all. I don't see any flaming actually going on here, though. On a side note, we had a MS rep talk to our team in person and tell us that their MSI setup can not support the features we need / are using now.

Comment: OK. In fact, primarily you have to assure, that your MSI is not trying to be repaired by anyone. Second, you have to bother for clean uninstall on you own. If you have only replaced existing files, it is ok at first. Third, you have  to decide what to do if it you want to build a new MSI setup of your product anyhow in the future. I would recommend to hear expert's voice on that.

Comment: Generally, I would not advise people thinking that the support is giving best answers only because they are employed by MS (or any other company). Or that the answer of support has to necessarily official whatever this may be. They have clearly very bright people in their company, but most of them are not support reps. Some of best MS experts may have already left the company, I know of some. In the support cases I was involved, in best you get a good Windows OR developer consultant (But how many people out there are extraordinary in both?) with _some_ MSI know how.

Comment: The answer is an answer. The question was "Is there a way?"  The answer is factually a no.  You have only manipulated ARP version. You haven't had any impact on MSI Product Version and Win32_Product (used by inventory software such as SCCM)  is unaffected also.  You also have a huge whole in your servicing pattern as you are working against Windows Installer.  Tom, I'm sorry you are offended by my blunt honesty. I have 20 years of setup experience with 12 of them on Windows Installer.  I've created thousands of installers and I've been down the road you are trying to go down.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I'm not offended. My down vote, as I stated, was the result of the answer not really being an answer. Your edit makes your statement more of an answer, kind of. There is a way, it's just not ideal to you or Microsoft.

Comment: It's people like yourself who ignore windows best practices that create application compatibility problems down the road.  You've been advised to do the right thing, it's up to you to heed that advice.

Comment: When best practices prevent a functional program under certain conditions, alternative options have to be taken. Best practices generally are a great thing to follow, but there can be specific situations where best practices don't apply. In my case, the best practices are not feasible because of the way the client is set up. My guess is, the absolute best approach to this problem would have been to create a completely custom installer. Doing so would have taken a lot more time and pushed us over deadlines. Programming is never simple and there is NEVER a one size fits all solution.

Comment: Sorry, I've been doing installers for 20 years and I know your opinion above is misguided.  I've worked for scores of customers who all thought they were special and they weren't.  Deadlines are met by leverage expert knowledge and experience not by taking shortcuts.

Answer (score -1):

The MSI Installed version can be updated by modifying the registry value for the installed application located in one of two places. On my Windows 8 PC, it is located at the following:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{MSI-GUID}`

It may also be located at:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{MSI-GUID}`

To update the version number shown on the Programs and Features screen, modify the registry value "DisplayVersion"

Comment: This "answer" fails to take into consideration HKCR\Installer\Products and the Win32_Product class.  This is a Windows Installer anti-pattern and should not be modeled in anyway.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Care to point out where exactly this would break down? I just tested uninstalling and updating and had no issues.

Comment: Test a major upgrade, or a minor upgrade, maybe even a patch and a repair. What do you think Windows will do when the version in the registry no longer matches the version in the cached MSI file, and doesn't match the version in the original MSI file that will be used to repair missing files?

Comment: @PhilDW Per discussion in other answers, repair has been disabled by means of non-distributing the MSI, patches happen only through our updater, and I tested uninstalling with major and minor changes to the version number.

Comment: You can't disable repair - you can only refuse to supply the original MSI when it is asked for.